# How to customize the existing image component (map/area functionality) in Adobe Cq5?

Tags: aem

There is an image, when I `hover` on the specific area of a image. I want to show another image in `CQ5`. Right now I have achieved this using `map,area,co-ordinates` concept, `onmouseover()` function I have changed the images. I have got the following things from the `dialog` from the user.
1)image which needs to appear when hovered
2)co-ordinates of the area.

My question is, I want to  `avoid` `getting the co-ordinates` from the user. The same map functionality is present in `default image component`, where should I go and `customize` the component, so that I can `add an extra textfield` in the component to just get the `image path` which needs to change on hover,and I want to add the `mouseover` functionality as well.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to know how to edit a dialog to add a text field? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @anotherdave : in the existing image component, there is map functionality available. i want to add a textfield in that map functionality tab . where is the jsp file to customize the map functinality ?

Comment: @anotherdave: right now the map fucntionality allows me to only add an href link for the area.i want to add an extra field where i can add, images path , which has to be showed when i hover on the each specific area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add an image map to an image dialog, I get the following outputted in Author mode:

```
<div class="genericImage cq-element-par_47image" id="cq-gen25">
    <img title="Triangle - Equilateral" usemap="#map_X" src="image">
    <map name="map_X" id="cq-gen117">
        <area shape="rect" coords="25,34,209,151" href="/path.html">
    </map>
</div>
```

Going by `/libs/foundation/components/image/image.jsp`, the `<map>` and the `<image>` are all rendered out by the `drawOut()` method of com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image.

If you want to change how the map is outputted, you would need to replace this method with your own code. The details of the map itself though are saved on the image node as a regular property called `imageMap`, so there's it's quite possible to:

1. Overlay the image component
2. Modify your version of the JSP (`apps/foundation/components/image/image.jsp`) to output the map, the href and the image as you need it (using `${properties.imageMap}` for the map/link and `${properties.fileReference}` for the image reference)
3. Write some CSS/JS to overlay your image from the href on hover.